# Compare pathnames in R and Python

Tags: python, r, filepath

This question appeared and was then deleted:

With Python, pathnames can be expressed in three ways:

```
mypath = r"C:\folder\temp.shp"    
mypath = "C:\\folder\\temp.shp"    
mypath = "C:/folder/temp.shp"
```

What are all of the ways pathnames can be expressed in R?

End of copied question. I cannot speak for the validity of the statements about Python, but was surprised that a simple search of SO did not pull up a good description of the R pathname (and OS-specific) issues. (and then my partially written answer was deleted along with the question.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For platform independence, you can use either forward slashes (`"C:/folder/temp.shp"`) or use `file.path` (e.g. `file.path('c:','folder','temp.shp')`.  The latter is particularly convenient for use with variables rather than using `paste`.

For instance, you could have the root directory stored in a variable in your `.Rprofile` on each computer, then use `file.path` to point to a specific file.

In Windows computer .Rprofile: `.db <- "C:/Dropbox"`
In OS/X or Linux computer .Rprofile: `.db <- "/home/foo/Dropbox"`

Then in your code you would call:

```
mypath <- file.path( .db, "folder", "temp.shp" )
```

@DWin has already pointed out the Windows-specific methods, which should be avoided in my opinion precisely because they are not platform-independent (and they tend to be more confusing to those who have not yet learned character escaping.

Answer (score 1):

The third version would work on all 3 of the OS-specific versions distributed on CRAN. (The Windows version would convert the forward-slashes to back-slashes.)
The second version could work, but only on the Windows version. The first version does not actually have any backslashes in it, because of the way character vectors are parsed in R, but instead has escape-F and escape-T which are not valid directory separators.

What Dirk said;

And note that `.Platform$file.sep)` returns a system independent version of the directory separator and see that @AriB.Friedman already pointed out that `?file.path` can be used to construct valid paths.

Comment: David, that is not correct as `C:/` works on only one of the three OSs.

Comment: Forward slashes are good, as are relative paths. Where to hook'em in is another story alltogther.  At work I have helper functions filling in the first argument for `file.path()` based on yje OS: Either `/foo`  or `\\somewhere\foo`.

Comment: In python, the first and second are identical strings. The `r"thing"` notation is a raw python string, where backslashes aren't escape characters. Hence `"\\foo" == r"\foo"` in python. So in python, the first one doesn't have escape-F or escape-T in it. Not sure if there's a way to express strings like that in R...

Comment: If you want a single backslash in R, it's "\\". If you want a single backslash in R regex patterns, it's "\\\\", ... unless perl =TRUE. I suppose you could also paste in: `intToUtf8(92)` which returns:`#[1] "\\"`